# Java - synchronized ArrayList still ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, arraylist, synchronized

I got an `final ArrayList<RoutingTableEntry> routingTable = new ArrayList<>();` which is accessed multiple times. 
But I only get at one Point an `ConcurrentModificationException` which is in the following Thread:

```
Thread checkReplies = new Thread(() -> {

    while (true) {

        synchronized (routingTable) {

            for (RoutingTableEntry entry : routingTable) { // throws it here

                // do smth
            }
        }

        // [...]
    }
 });
 checkReplies.start();
```

It throws the exception at the loop even though the `routingTable` is already synchronized. This thread gets only executed once per class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding/removing items in `routingTable` inside the `for` cycle ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't just use `Collections.synchronizedList()` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?

Comment: @Joe iterating a `Collections.synchronizedList` isn't the same as iterating a list in a synchronized block.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i call a method which removes then (should i make the method synchronized?)

Comment: @Stefanxyz This is the issue. You can't do it.

Comment: @Joe i didn't know this existed

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can i call a synchronized method which then changes the list? (Even though then the entire synchronized statement is (i think so at least) then useless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your comment in the original question, you **are removing items** in the `routingTable` while **you are iterating**.

You **can't** do it (also if the `routingTable` is synchronized)

```
for (RoutingTableEntry entry : routingTable) { // throws it here
     // routingTable.remove(....);
}
```

Comment: thanks i actually thought it was concurrent (@tevemadar mentioned it) and it makes now sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

1. You have **other** code in the class that modifies `routingTable`, and doesn't use `synchronized (routingTable)` when doing so. So when the other code modifies the list during that iteration, you get the error.
2. You're modifying the list where you have the comment "do smth". Just because you have have the list synchronized, that doesn't mean you can modify it while looping through with its iterator. You can't (except through the iterator itself, which would mean you couldn't use the enhanced `for` loop). (Sometimes you get away with it because of the details of the `ArrayList` implementation, but other times you don't.)

Here's an example of #2 ([live copy](http://ideone.com/jMx7Lx)):

```
var routingTable = new ArrayList<String>();
routingTable.add("one");
routingTable.add("two");
routingTable.add("three");
synchronized (routingTable) {
    for (String entry : routingTable) {
        if (entry.equals("two")) {
            routingTable.add("four");
        }
    }
}
```

That fails with JDK12's implementation of `ArrayList` (at least, probably others).

One key thing to understand is that synchronization and modifying the list during iteration are largely unrelated concepts. Synchronization (done properly) prevents multiple threads from accessing the list at the same time. But as you can see in the example above, just a single thread can cause a ConcurrentModificationException by modifying the list during the iteration. They only relate in that if you have one thread reading the list and another thread that may modify it, synchronization prevents the modification while the read is happening. Other than that, they're unrelated.

In a comment you've said:

> i call a method which removes then

If you're removing the entry for the loop, you can do that via a [list iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html)'s [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()) method:

```
for (var it = routingTable.listIterator(); it.hasNext; ) {
    var entry = it.next();
    if (/*...some condition...*/) {
        it.remove(); // Removes the current entry
    }
}
```

(There are also `add` and `set` operations.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean with "You can't (except ...).". Did you forget to complete the sentence or can't you change anything of the List within the synchronized statement?

Comment: @Stefanxyz - The sentence is complete, [list iterators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html) have some modification methods you can safely use during iteration. To use them, though, you have to explicitly use `listIterator` and a standard `for` or `while` or similar loop, you can't use the enhanced `for` loop (since it hides the iterator from you). See also the additions I've made to the answer: You're conflating two things that are largely unrelated (synchronization and concurrent modification).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized this already thanks to Gabriele Mariotti and tevemadar. I reworked the structure to an normal ´for´ loop which makes it then possible (reducing the index by list changes)

Answer (score 1):

`ConcurrentModificationException` is not necessarily 'concurrent' in the sense of threading, it can be 'concurrent' in the sense of that you shall not directly modify a collection at the same time when you are iterating over it.

It is in the docs too, for a long time (excerpt from Java7: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. **For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.**

And `for(x:y)` uses an iterator, which can easily end up being a 'fail-fast' one.